# Radio button values stored in Database?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

In vb.net,

i have 31 PAIRS of radio buttons Yes or No in a web form which will insert the value of radion buttons or text of radio buttons in a single table of 31 columns in SQL server. I grouped each pair of radio button (Y and N). How can I retrieve the selected radio button value of the group and insert it into MS sql server database table using one insert command in VB.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explain yourself better:

do you want to store 31 BOOLEAN values in ONE row?

or do you want to store 31 TEXT values in one row?

or do you want to store 31 BOOLEAN and/or TEXT values in 31 columns in one row?

Comment: I want to store Either Yes (1) or No (0) How??

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter to your SqlCommand like so:

```
Dim cmd as new sqlcommand("SQL Command Text Here", Conn)
cmd.parameters.add("@FieldA", sqldbtype.bit).value = IIF(FieldAYesChk.Checked, 1, 0)
cmd.parameters.add("@FieldB", sqldbtype.bit).value = IIF(FieldBYesChk.Checked, 1, 0)
cmd.parameters.add("@FieldC", sqldbtype.bit).value = IIF(FieldCYesChk.Checked, 1, 0)
cmd.parameters.add("@FieldD", sqldbtype.bit).value = IIF(FieldDYesChk.Checked, 1, 0)
```

etc...

Follow link for more information regarding SQL Server Bit data type:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

Comment: If i use Insert query to enter values in database, then how i declare in sql server for each radio button??

Comment: You could create a different column in a table for each set of radio buttons, then do "INSERT INTO TableName (FieldA, FieldB,....) VALUES (@FieldA, @FieldB,....)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but what i wanted to say is in sql-server how i declare data-types of radio-button and how to link to my front-end??

Comment: You can't declare a datatype of radio-button. A radio button is a control. However, if you want a Yes/No value in your database you can use a bit datatype, which stored 1 (Yes), 0 (No) or NULL